# Want to display first frame of video in app designer matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I am trying to show the first frame of a video on a GUI in app designer. So far, everything seems to process, and I am not receiving any errors, but the image I want is not showing. All I get is the UIAxes disappears, and nothing shows up.  When I copy this code and run it outside of app designer it runs fine, it just won't display the image I need in the GUI.

```
x= app.DirEditField.Value % app.DirEditField.Value is the video filename
obj=VideoReader(x); 
vid=read(obj); 
firstframe=read(obj,1); 
imshow(firstframe,'Parent',app.UIAxes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I literally just deleted the UIAxes object and put in a new one and it works perfectly.